# How to run All test cases of a single spec sequentially with closing the browser each time in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am new to Protractor but aware about the selenium.

Suppose there are 5 TCs in a single spec file and I want to run them sequentially.
Means one TC should be execute at one time but Protractor is running all those TCs simultaneously.

Also, I want to close the browser window after each TCs is being completed (No matter what is the result Pass / Fail).

Can you please help me out on it.

Comment: Protractor runs them sequentially - one after another- this is called Control Flow. Read about it [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md). The reason why you're seeing the tests executed at same time might be due to asynchronous execution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually wants to close the window and launch it again for each TC. Can I do it?

Comment: Use the `beforeEach` block to open and close the browser. It will be executed in each `describe` block.

Comment: First of all browser.open() function is not working for me. An error has been thrown as "no such function".
Second, I did try browser.restart() in before Each and application is now restarting the window but for my 2nd TC, it is not able to make connection with browser

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no function in protractor called,

```
  browser.open("");
```

Rather it should be,

```
  browser.get("");
```

Now your browser will open and launch the AUT. Then you can sequence control flow () , by mentioning beforeEach block for opening and closing the browser.